# What is keys which do not require encryption in KeyStore Provider?

Tags: android, encryption, keystore

I want to store my secret keys using Android KeyStore Provider (on Android 6 and above). But I can't understand one thing: is the keys will be deleted when user change settings of lock screen?

In changes list to Android 6 described:

> Keys which do not require encryption at rest will no longer be deleted
>   when secure lock screen is disabled or reset (for example, by the user
>   or a Device Administrator). Keys which require encryption at rest will
>   be deleted during these events.

But what is the keys which do not require encryption? Is it mean that I should choose between store keys unsafely (without encryption) or it will be erased when user changes settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keys that require user authentication are generated using `setAuthenticationRequired` on the `KeyGenParameterSpec` on API 23+:

```
KeyGenParameterSpec
  .Builder(...)
  .setUserAuthenticationRequired(requiresAuth)
  ...
  .build()
```

and using `setEncryptionRequired` on the `KeyPairGeneratorSpec` on API 19-22:

```
specBuilder = KeyPairGeneratorSpec.Builder(context)
if (requiresAuth) {
  specBuilder.setEncryptionRequired()
}
```